# Why isn't the HTML break tag acceptable anymore for top and bottom margins?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, line-break

I'm starting to think I'm making less with adsense now because of insufficient margins. I tried with CSS margins with using the margin and padding properties of applicable elements, but then I noticed something. When I disabled CSS, my page looks mostly like trash with words crammed together, almost no new lines, etc.

Some sources claim never to use consecutive HTML breaks. For example:

```
<br><br>
```

The funny thing is when I do add the breaks, the page appears more nicely to users who don't have javascript or CSS enabled.

So my question is, why is using multiple consecutive line breaks in HTML considered a bad practice when it improves accessibility (helps greatly with top and bottom margins for users with limited functionality browsers)?

As a side note, using consecutive line breaks takes fewer bytes than using any other tag that can produce a line break.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the paragraph tag?? I use the p tag even when presenting data.

Comment: I do for presenting actual text data, but to add just blank lines as margins, I'm better off with `<br>`.

Comment: Can you use a div with an id or class and a null back space nbsp?

Comment: I tend to be conservative on my use of the break tag- not while hacking of course, but for the final product. No reason for it, just what I do. I think I found using breaks were less predictable than anything else. I do not remember. ;-) Getting old.

Comment: I know you're presenting good ideas, but `<br>` is only 4 bytes where as `<div ID="X">&nbsp;</div>` is almost 25 bytes. I like to make my code small because 1. I want a good code/text ratio and 2. I want the download time to be small and I just find it ridiculous myself to use an opening and closing tag just for a simple line break when `<br>` works fine.

Comment: @Mike And if every div had a class assigned to it of "X", you could put down, once in your CSS, .X { margin-bottom:1em } and cover them all while keeping the DOM light.

Comment: You do not have to worry about code to content ratios- it is just bull squirt. HTML is quick to download regardless. It is good to make your code lean or course, but at what cost? There are trade-offs. Also site speed is relative anyway. If you are downloading within 1.5 -2 seconds total, you are faster than most sites. Trust me!! You would have to be particularly slow to really effect performance. Most all of my pages are relatively heavy code and content wise and I still download within 1.5 seconds total across almost 700,000 pages.

Comment: I run adsense on my site and adsense displays ads based on the content of the site.

Comment: But Adsense has nothing to do with code to content ratio or page speed. I am not sure how much traffic you get. But most of Adsense success come from traffic- lots of traffic. I saw a site with 800,000 page views a month getting less than $1500 in revenue. That is $0.001875 per page view which is in the realm of what most of us get without clicks. RPM is based upon clicks. Your biggest worry is getting page views and then clicks. If you get 1 click per 1000 page views, you are smokin hot on fire!! It can be more like 1 in 5000.

Comment: sometimes I'm somewhat above average with CPC but my RPM is often under average.

Comment: Part of that is also bid related. Some topics/sites do not get the higher or medium range bid. Remember that advertisers want people who are ready to buy. Any site must attract some element of people who are willing and capable to spend money. I changed my pages somewhat way down in the h3 tags toward money keywords and my RPM tripled. But for that to happen, my site had to begin to transition into another web market and be weighted against those sites. If you want to make money, you need to incorporate content that includes money keywords such as brand mentions such as vodka, cameras, etc.

Comment: But do that within the content and not for search. This is picked up in the bidding process. Also, keep in mind that a single word used only once way down on every page (assuming you have enough of them) can really effect search and results.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I need to find more money words too but at the same time I gotta blend it in to my site. The tough part of my site is that I'm in charge of the text myself and the rest of the team.... all they do is take pictures and upload pictures.

Answer (score 6):

> why is using multiple consecutive line breaks in HTML considered a bad practice

Because it breaks the fundamental principle of separation of concerns: by mixing the "content" and "presentation" layers. By using multiple `<br>`s to create "margins" you are embedding the presentation in the *content*. To change the "margins" you need to change the *content*. This ultimately makes the site harder (messy) to update. If sites are harder to update there's more chance of error, etc.

> the page appears more nicely to users who don't have <del>javascript or</del> CSS enabled

An extreme (to the point of being non-existent) edge case. Any user that has actively disabled CSS will be used to pages appearing mashed. (How do you disable CSS in the modern browser anyway?) I struggle to imagine that you have  *real users* that are using browsers that are so "limited [in] functionality" that they are incapable of this basic CSS. Any browsers that are purposefully designed to be very limited probably have alternative forms of navigation or are designed to be non-graphical anyway?

It's great to have pages that are at least readable with CSS disabled - it's a sign they are logically structured and are accessible. However, the width of a margin should not matter in this respect. And real users don't surf with CSS disabled.

> but `<br>` is only 4 bytes where as `<div ID="X">&nbsp;</div>` is almost 25 bytes

You shouldn't be using a DIV either. For "margins" you should be using CSS. If these margins are so critical to the layout then include them as part of an *embedded* stylesheet in the HEAD section - that way they are loaded with the page and the user cannot see a delay. (Whilst developing you still keep the embedded stylesheet external - separation of concerns - and embed it using a server-side technology when the page is served.)

Comment: I tried external stylesheets before and google tells me to optimize CSS for delivery and prioritize the styles. I have all my styles in `<head>` already. I'm creating for accessibility because I want the whole wide world to be able to access the site even with CSS disabled.

Comment: Google doesn't say put _all_ your styles in the `head` section; just the bare essential to get a working page in the users _viewport_. External stylesheets can be cached client-side, which is going to benefit site visitors in both speed and bandwidth. If you have a "single page website" (perhaps powered with AJAX) then yes, embed your entire stylesheet, but otherwise it's a no-no, certainly if your stylesheet is of any size.

Answer (score 1):

Because a line break is used to break a line and not add margin. The effect may appear the same but the semantics are not. If you want a margin on a div, use "margin".

You have people who turn CSS off? I doubt that. You have visitors with javascript turned off? Those who know how to do that are the same who know what to expect as a result.

Comment: Here's the funny thing... when I added breaks on my adsense ads via `<br><br>`  my income went up by a cent within two hours. Before the change, I made only one cent for the entire day. go figure. I do appreciate your answer but I just don't understand why it must be incorrect semantically as a whole.

Comment: @Mike It's incorrect semantically because your usage is not semantically correct. You are attributing design success with adding incorrect elements. If margin is what you need, use margin. Breaks won't make the difference.

Comment: I'm just thinking now If I define all margins in CSS for all applicable tags, and I use a browser where the styles are applied later even tho they are executed in the head of the document (likely because of slow computer etc), then I have a feeling the document will shift as the margin is then applied.

Comment: @Mike Styles are applied after CSS is downloaded, not before.

Comment: @Mike If your daily AdSense income is measured in cents, you are engaged in what we call _premature optimization_. And even if it were dollars, I'd probably still think the same thing. Anyway, remember that your site's content should be semantically appropriate, because not everyone uses what you normally think of as a web browser. What you should be focusing on at this early stage of your site is high quality content.

Comment: I had moments where I earned double digit cents, and I even had moments where I earned $1 - $2 a day. The reason why I focused on appearance is because I'm trying to prevent invalid click activity while at the same time, reduce code size. I have quality content, especially on my home page. I just think there's more to adsense than just content only.

Comment: Now this is getting even more interesting. My income went up more. I shouldn't be commenting about dollars and cents too much but those line breaks the way I am doing them certainly help me.